# How to set Flutter default elevations

Tags: flutter

How can I set default elevations to zero for all flutter widgets e.g. including `DropdownButton` and `RaisedButton`?

I want to create a flat color app.

Comment: you cannot do that - `DropdownButton` has for example hardcoded default elevation set to `8`

Comment: it is not hard coded !! see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/elevation.html , I can change it per Widget

Comment: it is hardcoded: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c969b8af7b/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart#L816 - it means that if you do not specify any `elevation` for `DropdownButton` the value of `8` will be used - also the link you posted says: *"Defaults to 8, the appropriate elevation for dropdown buttons."*

Comment: What about `RaisedButton` ?